# "Cannot convert object to int"

Tags: c#

I'm just starting to learn C#, and I'm currently working on my first ever real project. I'm supposed to generate age and gender for passengers on a bus, and then be able to print out all this information for each passenger in the form of a number and a letter (23M for example). I cannot get it to work, however, and I don't know why.

```
namespace Bus
{
//define Passenger with information about age and gender
class Passenger
{
    //random number generator
    Random random = new Random();
    
    int age;
    string gender;
    //creates an array of characters so the index numbers may be
    //used in the random number generator
    char[] genderChars = "MF".ToCharArray();
    
    public int passenger
    {
        set
        {
            //makes age random number between 12 and 90 - the age range
            //where people typically ride the bus alone without problems
            age = random.Next(11, 91);
            //picks a random number between 0 and 1, which correspond to
            //the symbols M and F in CharArray
            gender = (genderChars[random.Next(0, 1)].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class I've written for generating a passenger. Inserting them into the array is no trouble; the problem comes with printing them out afterward.

```
class Buss
{
    Passenger[] passengerArray = new Passenger[25];
    public int numberOfPassengers;

    public void print_buss()
    {
        foreach(int temp in passengerArray)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            catch(Exception g)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(g.Message);
            }
        }
```

I know this piece of code is a bit nonsensical, but I'm trying to solve one problem at a time. Right now, I get the error message "Cannot convert type 'Bus.Passenger' to 'int' (CS0030)". But isn't Bus.Passenger already an int? I did write "public int passenger" in the first bit.

In short, I just can't get this code to work and I don't really know what to do. I already feel out of my depth in terms of how much I've actually read at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `foreach(Passenger temp in passengerArray)`

Comment: The error is clear. A `Passenger`isn't an int, so it makes no sense to use `int temp` to hold a `Passenger` instance. Given that `Passenger` doesn't have a `ToString()` overload, `Console.WriteLine(temp);` won't print anything useful eitherr

Comment: For the record, `random.Next(0, 1)` will never give you `1`. The upper bound parameter is _exclusive_.

Comment: Sorry but there are so many errors here that to fix everything there is a lot to change. (No initialization of the passenger array, missing constructors in the Passenger and Buss, non static Random variable in the Passenger class and other errors pointed in the comments above

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is clear, you are enumerating the `passengerArray` which is a collection that stores `Passenger` instances. But in the `foreach` you treat them like `int`:

```
foreach(int temp in passengerArray)
```

So you need to use the right type:

```
foreach(Passenger passenger in passengerArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(passenger);
}
```

You should override `ToString` in `Passenger` to provide something useful in `WriteLine`.

Following things to note:

- don't store a `Random` in `Pessenger` since a pessenger should not be responsible to create an instance of itself randomly. Instead your calling code can create instances.
- provide public properties for `Age` and `Gender` and so on.
- provide a constructor that let initialize a `Passenger` instead of the `passenger` property